# PHP regex -- locate ampersand that IS NOT an HTML character entity reference

Tags: php, regex

I'm able to match for an HTML character entity reference with the following regex:

```
$pattern = "%\&\w+\;%";
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to match an ampersand that is *explicitly not* one of these character entity references. Such as:

```
this &pattern
or this &;
```

It seems like I should try using the negation pattern, for example, `\&(^\w+\;)`, but after much experimentation and study I am very stuck.

For clarification, I am trying to locate illegal ampersands and double quotes inside of HTML attributes. The problem is, ampersand is legal in some cases because it is part of the character entity reference syntax. I want to isolate the ampersands that are illegal. Examples:

```
&illegal
some string with & is also illegal
&amp; <-- not illegal
```

---

I found out what I needed; a negative lookahead (in PHP, that's `?!` as outlined in [PHP: Assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php))

```
$pattern = "%&(?!\w+;)|(\")%";
```

Comment: In your example, `&pattern` is invalid HTML.

Comment: `&` and `;` have no special meaning in `regex`; there is no need to escape them.

Comment: ahh ok, I see. Well, it's for the attribute value of a meta-tag. Won't ampersands and double quotes break that if I load the data in?

Comment: Can you please clarify your clarification, again. you say you're trying to locate illegal ampresands but I'm not clear what is *illegal*? You state `with & is` as illegal but also that ` &amp; ` is *not* illegal. So the ampersand is legal as long as it's 5 characters long instead of just one? That's a worthless differentiaton to make imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say you build your checks into a single `preg_replace_callback()` method:

Code ([demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de4ca8cdd3c00661e7693be35f2dc1174b37b7f4)):

```
$string='À    A with grave accent    &Agrave;    &#x00C0;
&illegal some string with & is also illegal &amp; <-- not illegal
Ê    E with circumflex    &Ecirc;    &#x00CA;
Δ    Delta    &Delta;    &#x0394;';

echo preg_replace_callback('/&\S*/',function($m){return $m[0]===htmlentities(html_entity_decode($m[0]))?$m[0]:'POO!';},$string);
//         decode then encode and check against the original ---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### Output:

```
À    A with grave accent    &Agrave;    POO!
POO! some string with POO! is also illegal &amp; <-- not illegal
Ê    E with circumflex    &Ecirc;    POO!
Δ    Delta    &Delta;    POO!
```

Notice that my anonymous function call doesn't currently have a condition that checks for Unicode expressions that start with `&`. If you also want to handle these, then simply build in another condition.  There are probably more considerations than I am aware of (this may be a rabbit hole project).

Answer (score 1):

- You are using PHP (according to your tag).
- You are checking for HTML entity references.
- You want to identify (*and in my example replace*) ampersands that are **not** HTML entities.
- You want to preserve the `&amp;` entity reference, but you want to find the `&` plaintext equivalent.

So... to make use of PHP outside of regex functionality and use PHP's own native identification for HTML entities, do this:

```
 $string = " some text containing - &amp; stuff&things ";


 $string2 = str_ireplace("&amp;", "__PLACEHOLDER__", $string);
 $string2 = html_entity_decode($string2, ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");
 $string2 = preg_replace("/&/","<replacementValue>", $string2);
 $string2 = str_ireplace("__PLACEHOLDER__", "&amp;", $string2);
 $string2 = htmlentities($string2, ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8", false);
```

That contains several stages:

- Line 1: because for some odd reason you want to preserve HTML ampersands, but not plaintext ones, these can be converted to `PLACEHOLDER` values. Placeholder values should not contain HTML entities.
- Line 2: Then, once the plain ampersands have been taken out you can convert all the other HTML encoded entities to their respective characters, removing these ampersands you wish to keep.
- Line 3: Then, replace your remaining target ampersands with whatever (or do whatever you need with them.... whatever.
- Line 4: swap back the placeholder
- Line 5: Swap back the other decoded entities back to there HTML encoded forms (if required).

If you don’t need to preserve `&amp;` then you can do this in 2-3 lines.

Output (HTML):

> ```
>  some text containing - & stuff<replacementValue>things
> ```

**And**

Input:

```
$string = "     &illegal
          some string with & is also illegal
          &amp; <-- not illegal ";
```

Output:

> ```
>          <replacementValue>illegal
>          some string with <replacementValue> is also illegal
>          &amp; <-- not illegal
> ```

Reference:

- [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)
- [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: My use case is that an admin is entering custom values for attributes on the site's metatags. Basically, I want to make sure they don't put in anything that will cause the site to crash; that just seems like double quotes and ampersands to me, is that right? I suppose, as you point out, I could just run html_entity_encode on the strings to make sure they don't have any symbols that will break the string. I'll play around with that and see how it works, thanks.

Comment: @DanielThompson, for that case I would suggest using `htmlentities()` and [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) PHP functions. as well as employing a [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) on your website.